# Trying to implement a simple slideshow - Wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I´ve trying to implement this simple slideshow: http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/doZNMo

But im not having sucess and i dont know what the problem is, the only thing that shows up is the last image of the slideshow, i added the path to the js file, checked if the name are correct, but stil no luck.

```js
var seconds = 2; //time beetwen auto slide
var delay = 8; //time to restart auto slide

var slider = $('#slider');
var images = $('#slider .images');
var controls = $('<div>').addClass('controls');
slider.after(controls);
var width = images.width();
var slideClick = function() {
  var b = $(this);
  $('.controls div').removeClass('current');
  b.addClass('current');
  var index = b.index();
  images.css('left', -1 * index * width);
};
$('#slider .images img').each(function(i) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.css('left', i * width);
  var button = $('<div>');
  controls.append(button);
  if (i == 0) {
    button.addClass('current')
  }
  button.click(function() {
    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
    slideClick.apply(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
    }, delay * 1000);
  });
});
var autoSlide = function() {
  var next = $('.controls .current').next();
  if (next.length) {
    slideClick.apply(next);
  } else {
    var first = $('.controls div').first();
    slideClick.apply(first);
  }
};
var autoSlideInterval = setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
```

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}

.mail2.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider .images {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  left: 0;
}
#slider .images img {
  position: absolute;
}
.controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.controls div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.controls .current {
  background: firebrick;
}

.barra2 {
  background-image: url('img/barra2.png');
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 21.6%;
}

.mobile {
  background-image: url("img/fundo3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 44.4%;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .invisi {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 14%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.mobile .invisi:hover {
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.mobile .appstore {
  right: 26.5%;
}

.mobile .googleplay {
  right: 11.5%;
}

.contact {
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 12px 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form>
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
          <a href="#">Get started for free</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
      <form>
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <a href="#">Get started for free</a>
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FFCC47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-2&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-3&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=4763FF&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-4&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-4" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="barra2"></div>

    <div class="mobile">
      <a href="#" class="invisi appstore"></a>
      <a href="#" class="invisi googleplay"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="subjet" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <a href="#">Send</a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could i give the total new solution, but i bet it's easy to use and understand, has the same effect.

Comment: You want to provide a different way ? Sure, go for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your jquery wasn't included. Here is the same code with jquery included and the slideshow working.

```js
var seconds = 2; //time beetwen auto slide
var delay = 8; //time to restart auto slide

var slider = $('#slider');
var images = $('#slider .images');
var controls = $('<div>').addClass('controls');
slider.after(controls);
var width = images.width();
var slideClick = function() {
  var b = $(this);
  $('.controls div').removeClass('current');
  b.addClass('current');
  var index = b.index();
  images.css('left', -1 * index * width);
};
$('#slider .images img').each(function(i) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.css('left', i * width);
  var button = $('<div>');
  controls.append(button);
  if (i == 0) {
    button.addClass('current')
  }
  button.click(function() {
    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
    slideClick.apply(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
    }, delay * 1000);
  });
});
var autoSlide = function() {
  var next = $('.controls .current').next();
  if (next.length) {
    slideClick.apply(next);
  } else {
    var first = $('.controls div').first();
    slideClick.apply(first);
  }
};
var autoSlideInterval = setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
```

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}

.mail2.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider .images {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  left: 0;
}
#slider .images img {
  position: absolute;
}
.controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.controls div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.controls .current {
  background: firebrick;
}

.barra2 {
  background-image: url('img/barra2.png');
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 21.6%;
}

.mobile {
  background-image: url("img/fundo3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 44.4%;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .invisi {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 14%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.mobile .invisi:hover {
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.mobile .appstore {
  right: 26.5%;
}

.mobile .googleplay {
  right: 11.5%;
}

.contact {
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 12px 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form>
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
          <a href="#">Get started for free</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
      <form>
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <a href="#">Get started for free</a>
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FFCC47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-2&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-3&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=4763FF&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-4&w=350&h=250" alt="Image-4" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="barra2"></div>

    <div class="mobile">
      <a href="#" class="invisi appstore"></a>
      <a href="#" class="invisi googleplay"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="subjet" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <a href="#">Send</a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copy pasted all code but isnt working, i dont know why.

Comment: is your jquery file where you say it is? In the console of yours I noticed it didn't recognize $ sign, ie jquery wasn't loaded

Comment: yes, it is on the same folder as the others scripts, this is weird.

Comment: I dont know what to do, i tried to storage jquery localy still dont work.

Comment: what does the console say

Comment: What you mean, console ?

Comment: press F12, go to console, you should see some red errors

Comment: it can't find your js

Comment: Yea, i accidently changed the path on HTML, i fixed it and it remains the same, that errror has gone.

Comment: so check the jquery path, if its still failing there should be an error in the console.

Comment: Can i upload my project so you can take a look ? Im getting desesperated ;/

Comment: make a js fiddle/codepen, and share a link, I'll look at it

Comment: so besides missing js/imgs the slideshow looks fine, what seems to be the issue

Comment: Sorry, what js misses ? and images ?

Comment: jsfiddle can't load local images/js so in the console there are errors about missing images and js files. What is the big issue? The slideshow that you had questions about originally works fine. I think you should look up some basic tutorials on js, js debugging, and html.

Comment: Whatever, im just getting even more confused. Thanks for your help.